# counting distinct value does not works in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to figure out the number of columns' vector, using `length(unique(x))` in r shiny.
However, it doesn't work in shiny app.

The codes are below.

```
library(shiny)

    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      selectInput("sel","select",colnames(mtcars)),
      textOutput("results")
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      output$results <- renderText({
        length(unique(input$sel))
      })
      
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The results of `length(unique(input$sel))` is `1`, regardless of its real number of distinct values.

How could I fix this work?

Comment: you can select only one value at a time, therefore the count will also be one. If you want to collect multiple values you could look into  `?selectizeInput`,...

Comment: @TonioLiebrand Thanks, but what I want to see is not the number of selected input, but n_distinct of the selected value. For example, ```cyl``` in ```mtcars``` has 3 vectos, 4,6,8, so the results should be ```3```, not ```1```. Any advice for this one?

Comment: ah then you are looking for `length(unique(mtcars[, input$sel]))`.

Comment: @TonioLiebrand Thank you very much! It worked. But the code you mentioned does not work in reactive data. ```data <- reactive({data.table::fread(input$file0$datapath)})``` and ```input$a``` for selectInput, ```length(unique(data[,input$a], na.rm=T))``` is not working, warning ```object of type 'closure' is not subsettable```. Could you help me why?

Comment: you could try `length(unique(data()[,input$a], na.rm=T))`. But this does not seem to be part of your code in the question. You should try to focus your questions and follow up with some tutorials about reactivity in shiny.

Comment: @TonioLiebrand Got it. Thank you for your advice.